# svn doesn't commit .o files, but why?

Tags: svn, command-line, commit

I found that svn doesn't commit my .o files by default. I've checked dir attributes - no any .o specific rules was found.

Is there a list of files that svn do not commit by default, as .o?

Comment: Don't commit build products to your version control system.

Comment: I'm adding sources the following way: `svn add <dirname>`, and the .o files in <dirname> folder do not appeared in svn checkouts.

Comment: that's what global-ignores does; see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at global-ignores in your configuration file.

The standard location of this file on a *nix system will be *~/.subversion/config*.

Answer (score 0):

SVN only commits the files that you `svn add` first. If you did not run `svn add` on an `*.o` file (and this is usually the case because you would `svn add` the source files before the project is built) then it will be ignored.