# Commit a *.o file is not possible

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I want to commit a object file via subclipse. I know it's not a good "style" to that, but I have to do that.

I found this via google:

[svn doesn't commit .o files, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502776/svn-doesnt-commit-o-files-but-why)

But that is not exactly what I searching for. I don't want to do the subversion topic via command line.

I changed the subclibse/config file // I deleted `*.o` from `global ignores`

But it is even not possible to commit it in the Eclipse Team menu. It is grayed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your *.o files are unversioned on your svn repository, since they are newly produced, it must do a "svn add" before "svn commit"