# SVN ignores .o file with svn add command even if I remove the .o from ignore-list

Tags: svn, ignore, object-files

Before marking my question as duplicate and referring to this: [svn doesn't commit .o files, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502776/svn-doesnt-commit-o-files-but-why) , I have to say I already checked the svn config file in AppData where ignore list is specified (I am using Windows). However, when I remove the .o from the list of global-ignores, svn still ignores my object files when I try to add them.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

1. **Commented** list of `global-ignores` in `[miscellany]` section contains default values, which are used in case of none touched in it (if you want to exclude anything, you must a/ remove unwanted pattern b/ uncomment key)
2. There are 3 (three) way to define ingores in SVN, you (probably) check only one: runtime configuration

Hint:

Re-read ["Ignoring Unversioned Items"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) in SVN Book (I hope, you use at least 1.8.* version) carefully and test the rest `svn:ignore` and `svn:global-ignores` properties (immediate and inherited)